# Prototype Ajax.Updater evaluate string before the update

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

here's my code:

```
new Ajax.Updater('container', url, {
    method: "get",
    onLoading: function () {
        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = "Loading...";
    },
    on200: function(response) {
        if(response.responseText.match(/WhatImLookingFor/)) {
            window.location = "leNewURL";
        }
    },
    onComplete: function(response) {
        //do other cool stuff
    }
});
```

What I'm trying to do is intercept the response before `container` gets updated and if the text in the response matches `WhatImLookingFor`, I want to redirect the user to `leNewURL`. With the code above this is happening, but not before the update, so it looks quirky. Is there anyway that I can intercept right before the update happens or do I have to resort to other hacks like hiding `container` and show it only if there's no match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to customize the behavior of your Ajax call like that I would recommend using the base `Ajax.Request()` http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Request/

```
new Ajax.Request(url, {
    method: "get",
    onLoading: function () {
        $('container').update("Loading...");
    },
    onComplete: function(response) {
        if(response.responseText.match(/WhatImLookingFor/)) {
            window.location = "leNewURL";
        }
        else {
            //do other cool stuff
            $('container').update(response.responseText);
        }
    }
});
```

I swapped out the `document.getElementById()` with the `$()` utility method as its less to type and includes all of PrototypeJS's Element methods

Comment: I suspected this was what I was going to have to do, but was hoping for a hook to be there... Either way, Thanks